# OpenAPI & spring-doc not finding all mappings in a controller class

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

This is a bit weird. springdoc-openapi-ui v1.2.32, the generated docs contain only a few of the mappings within a controller.

Example:

```
    @Operation(
            summary = "Foo",
            description = "Foo"
    )
    @PostMapping(path="/v1/foo")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> postFoo(@RequestBody FooRequestObject searchRequest, HttpServletRequest request){ ... }


    @Operation(
            summary = "Bar",
            description = "Bar"
    )
    @GetMapping(path="/v1")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> getBar(@RequestBody BarRequestObject request, HttpServletRequest request){ ... }


    @Operation(
            summary = "Bar",
            description = "Bar"
    )
    @PostMapping(path="/v1")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> postBar(@RequestBody BarRequestObject request, HttpServletRequest request){ ... }
```

Docs are generated only for `postBar` and `getBar` services, the other path is ignored.

What I've tried:

1. Originally both POST methods were named `post`. I renamed to avoid conflict.
2. I am not setting a controller level path.
3. Checked annotation imports
4. Not hitting a cached version of the doc

If I add another service to the controller (with or without the annotation tag), it also does not show in the generated Swagger. For example:

```
@GetMapping(path="/test")
public String getTest(){
    return "test";
}
```

If I add this method to a brand new controller, doc is generated.

Thanks

**Edit**
Config class

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI springOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("My API")
                .description("My API service documentation. ")
                .version("v1.0")
                .license(new License().name("Terms of Use").url("https://myapi.com/terms.html")));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible copy of the code that shows this error?

Comment: I can't, but I can add anything needed to the original question that may be helpful.

Comment: Can you share the properties in `application.properties` (or its equivalent) if any

Comment: Also I see that `(@RequestBody BarRequestObject request, HttpServletRequest request)` is wrong as both the parameters have same name which leads to compile error. And I've tried the current code with modifications to fix errors and it does work for me

Comment: The error is just a typo in my obfuscation, the code itself is correct and builds fine. This is the portion of the `application.properties`: `springdoc.paths-to-match=/api/v1,/v2,/v3,/status`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you are facing is caused by the fact that you have used level-1 references for `paths-to-match` and that's causing Springdoc to filter the endpoints that are available **only** on the specified paths.

```
springdoc.paths-to-match=/api/v1,/v2,/v3,/status
```

The above property makes a match for endpoints that **start and end** with `/v2`, `/v3`, `/status`, `/api/v1`. This fails to match for endpoints that maybe of the form like `/users/v2/` or even `/v2/users` etc.

Though there's no support for full regex to specify the endpoints you would like to include, but there's basic support for `**` that can help you specify the levels that you would like to include/exclude.

Consider the below examples

```
springdoc.paths-to-match=/**/v1/**/
```

It'll include any endpoint that has `/v1/` in it. Examples like `/users/v1/`, `/v1/dasboard` and also `/user/v1/dashboard`.

```
springdoc.paths-to-match=/v2/**
```

It'll match only endpoints starting with `/v2` and going n-level deep. Examples like `/v2/dashboard` will be included but `/users/v2/something` will be excluded.

```
springdoc.paths-to-match=/**/v1
```

It'll only match paths that end at `/v1`. Examples like `/users/v1` will be matched while those like `/v1/user` will not be matched.

Alternatively, you can also update your `Bean` to do the same. But note that properties files take precedence over bean config.

```java
// you existing bean here

// Define an API group that'll include specific version. Can be helpful in versioning the APIs.
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi hideApis() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("default")
            .pathsToExclude("/api/v2/**", "/v2/**", "/**/v3/**")
            .pathsToMatch("/v1/**", "/api/v1/**")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: How does having a context path to spring applicatoin affect this?

Comment: You should sill be able to include the context path as `/**/v3/**`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was excluded in OpenApi config

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi api() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("REST API")
            .pathsToMatch("/api/**", "/token")  <-- need to be added here
            .build();
}
```